# Frontend Checkout: Billing Address Form Fields Do Not Appear

Tags: magento2.3.2

[image]

When I check out on the front end and untick the "Billing and shipping address is the same" box, no new fields pop up to insert a billing address. This problem persists on all themes including Magento Luma/Default theme. I am unsure how to begin troubleshooting this to determine the cause, I hope so

[image]

Comment: Did you seen any JS errors in browsers console?

Comment: knockout.js:3391 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "template: function(){return detailsTemplate }"
Message: detailsTemplate is not defined

Comment: in https://domainname/pub/static/version1620831580/frontend/organica/organica_default/en_GB/knockoutjs/knockout.js

Comment: pls help sir.i am unable to figure out.its very urgent

Comment: It would be great if you can add error trace or at least screenshot of error to your question.

Comment: sir,added screenshot

Comment: when unchecking checkbox no billing address is displaying

Comment: can you please check sir.i am new to magento

Comment: Seems your troubles comes from the `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address.html` template. If you overwrite the base billing-address component, just add the `detailsTemplate` parameter to the `defaults`. If you are using custom component to render billing address on the checkout page, it must extend the origignal `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js` component. Check all installed modules for the `billing-address` modifications/mixins.

Comment: Sir, i am using codilar magento 2 Gst extension. in that app\code\Codilar\Gst\view\frontend\web\js\view\billing-address.js it is using.is this the reason for that issue.